# Tibco Spotfire - Calculate average only if there are minimum 3 values in a column - see desc

Tags: average, spotfire, minimum, calculation

I want to calculate average in Spotfire only when there are minimum 3 values. if there are no values or just 2 values the average should be blank

[image]

Raw data:

```
Product       Age          Average
1
2
3             10      
4             12   
5             13             11
6
7             18 
8             19 
9             20             19
10            21             20
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could really do this is with 3 calculated columns. Insert these calculated columns in this order:

- `If(Min(If([Age] IS NULL,0,[Age])) over (LastPeriods(3,[Product]))<>0,1) as [BitFlag]`
- `Avg([Age]) over (LastPeriods(3,[Product])) as [TempAvg]`
- `If([BitFlag]=1,[TempAvg]) as [Average]`

This will give you the following results. You can ignore / hide the two columns you don't care about.

**RESULTS**

```
+---------+-----+---------+------------------+------------------+
| Product | Age | BitFlag |     TempAvg      |     Average      |
+---------+-----+---------+------------------+------------------+
|       1 |     |         |                  |                  |
|       2 |     |         |                  |                  |
|       3 |  10 |         |               10 |                  |
|       4 |  12 |         |               11 |                  |
|       5 |  13 |       1 | 11.6666666666667 | 11.6666666666667 |
|       6 |     |         |             12.5 |                  |
|       7 |  18 |         |             15.5 |                  |
|       8 |  19 |         |             18.5 |                  |
|       9 |  20 |       1 |               19 |               19 |
|      10 |  21 |       1 |               20 |               20 |
|      11 |     |         |             20.5 |                  |
|      12 |  22 |         |             21.5 |                  |
|      13 |  36 |         |               29 |                  |
|      14 |     |         |               29 |                  |
|      15 |  11 |         |             23.5 |                  |
|      16 |  23 |         |               17 |                  |
|      17 |  14 |       1 |               16 |               16 |
+---------+-----+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Scsimon, thanks so much for taking time and helping me on this one. But I have one more issue to be fixed.I have attached one more image as well, when i used the same solution you provided it is not working. Kindly help.

Comment: @BULB what's the problem? With the sample data you gave, it works perfectly. What you have posted is a cross table. What I have shown you how to do is insert a calculated column into your original data, which is what the original question was in relation to since there were no aggregations.

Comment: When I am adding data to product 1 and 2, it is showing average for product 1 and 2. Ideally it should not happen because for product 1 there is no previous data for 3 moving average. product 2 has only data for product 2 and 1.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions I listed out to create your calculated values? Are you ONLY wanting this formula for a cross table? It can not be both. You need to provide more details. My answer is correct to the original question. If you have a new question open up a new thread.

Comment: Sure Thanks @scsimon. Thanks for your help